# Algorithm to find all primes from 2 to 1000 not working

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

Here's a piece of code to compute all primes from 2 to 1000 using the statement, that a number n is a prime number iff:

[image]

In the first version I think that I implemented the algorithm correctly:

```
public class Giuga {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 2;

        while(n<=1000){
            int k = 1;
            long sum = 0;
            while(k<=n-1){
                sum = sum+(long)Math.pow((double)k,(double)n-1);
                k++;
            }
            if(sum%n==n-1){
                System.out.println(n + " is a prime.");
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

But, since the variable `sum` grows rapidly, an overflow happens and after the prime number 17 there will be no output anymore.

To prevent that I have to use this:

[image]

Well, I did that and here is my 2. version:

```
public class Giuga {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 2;

        while(n<=1000){
            int k = 1;
            long sum = 0;
            while(k<=n-1){
                sum = sum+((long)Math.pow((double)k%n,(double)n-1))%n; //Here are the changes
                k++;
            }
            if(sum%n==n-1){
                System.out.println(n + " is a prime.");
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I did it correctly, but now the output stops after the prime number 13.

I'm trying to find my mistake for quite some time now. What am I doing wrong?
There must be 168 primes from 2 to 1000.

Comment: Uhm... that equation looks like Fermat's Little theorem applied to all possible bases. But if this is it then it's only a *necessary* condition, but not a *sufficient* one to find all primes. Charmicael numbers should satisfy that equation too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `double`s, which only have about 16 digits of precision, aren't precise enough to maintain the correct remainders for calculations on high enough numbers.

You can switch to `long`s and perform you own modular exponentiation.

```
int k = 1;
long sum = 0;
while(k<=n-1){
    long pow = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        pow = (pow * k) % n;
    sum = (sum + pow)%n;
    k++;
}
```

This algorithm could be improved by changing this straightforward modular exponentiation to using modular exponentiation by repeated squaring, and it's not the most efficient prime finding algorithm, but it is now correct.

```
2 is a prime.
3 is a prime.
5 is a prime.
7 is a prime.
11 is a prime.
13 is a prime.
17 is a prime.
19 is a prime.
23 is a prime.
29 is a prime.
31 is a prime.
```

(snip)

```
977 is a prime.
983 is a prime.
991 is a prime.
997 is a prime.
```

To make it modular exponentiation by repeated squaring, replace

```
long pow = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    pow = (pow * k) % n;
```

with

```
long pow = 1;
long square = k;
int exp = n - 1;
while (exp > 0)
{
    if ((exp & 1) == 1)
    {
        pow = (pow * square) % n;
    }
    square = (square * square) % n;
    exp >>= 1;
}
```

It tests each bit of the exponent in succession, and multiplies the current square in to `pow` if it's set.

Answer (score 3):

Java `double`s (i.e., the outputs of `pow`) do not represent large numbers precisely enough to yield a correct remainder. You should switch to [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: But is there any other way using modular exponentiation besides BigInteger in Java?

Comment: @de_dust Implement it yourself? The squaring method is pretty fast and is probably 10 lines of code.

Comment: @de_dust about half way through the wiki article under the "Right-to-left binary method" contains the pseudo code for the method. Translate that into Java and you got your answer! Just tested it myself and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the BigInteger class for large number computations

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    BigInteger N = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n));
    BigInteger N_MINUS_1 = N.subtract(BigInteger.ONE); 

    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int k = 1;  k < n; k++)
        sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k)).modPow(N_MINUS_1,N)).mod(N);
    return sum.equals(N_MINUS_1);
}
```

It's interesting though that **this is a variation of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)**, for each k in the sum Σ

k^(n-1)%n should be 1, else this number is not prime! So, if we find a k that k^(n-1)%n != 1, we can stop calculations. The above algorithm can be rewritten as:

```
private static boolean isPrimeFermat(int n) {
    BigInteger N = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n));
    BigInteger N_MINUS_1 = N.subtract(BigInteger.ONE); 

    for (int k = 1;  k < n; k++){
        if (new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k)).modPow(N_MINUS_1, N).equals(BigInteger.ONE) == false)
            return false;
    }       
    return true;
}
```

Voilà!

Comment: It works, but I don't really understand, why every summand has to be 1 (mod n). Can you explain this? I do understand, that if every summand is 1 (mod n), it is a prime, but why is this the only case?

Comment: Sidenote: This is much faster than my solution of course (because it was written by a bunch of smart software engineers instead of me ^^).

Comment: It's actually a sum-variation of Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Thanks for adding that into the answer. So basically you saw that the summands correspond to an expression that can be checked for Fermats little theorem. I though you deduced it (`a^k mod n == 1 forall a <=> n is prime`) from OPs initial theorem (`sum mod n==n-1 <=> n is prime`) and didn't get how you did that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your powers are too big as well (guess what 999^999 is). So you have to calculate the power as well using stepwise `(ab) mod n = ((a mod n)(b mod n)) mod n` (*modular exponentiation*):

```
public class Giuga {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                count++;
                System.out.printf("%d is prime\n", i);
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Found %d primes.\n", count);
    }

    // checks if number is a prime
    private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        int bigSum = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= number - 1; k++) {
            bigSum = (bigSum + calcPowMod(k, number - 1, number)) % number;
        }
        return bigSum % number == number - 1;
    }

    // calculates (a^b)%mod, making sure that intermediate results are always < max(a^2,mod)
    private static int calcPowMod(int a, int b, int mod) {
        int pow = 1;
        for (int k = 1; k <= b; k++) {
            pow = (pow * a) % mod;
        }
        return pow;
    }
}
```